# How to embed sfDoctrineGuardPlugin signin form into an existing template (homepage) and have it take on the template it occurs in

Tags: php, html, css, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm working with the Symfony Framework,

I have installed the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin. I already have my own homepage design and I'm trying to embed my sfGuardAuth signin/login fields into my homepage. I want them to use my homepage design too.

I paste this into one of my table rows: `<?php echo $form['username']->render() ?>` 
which is basically the field for "username". But for some reason all the things on my homepage disappear e.g. logo, original login fields which I intend to replace and also my sign up fields.

I have no idea how to solve this and symfony documentation for the guard plugin isn't coming across so clear to me.

So I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction or explain what I need to do.

So again what I want to do is embed sfDoctrineGuardPlugin signin form into an existing template (homepage). I want the signin form to take on the layout of the existing template.

Help is appreciated..
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you just echo $form? Could be a number of things... Can you tell us more about the layout you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an error in your code.  Have you tried to access the site via the frontend_dev.php file?  Does it generate any error messages?

When you say you are using your own design, the design is still part of the Symfony framework right?  As in, you are using the WEB/CSS folder for your stylesheet, and the layout.php file for your main page layout?

What you are trying to accomplish shouldn't be an issue.